# What does placing \ at the end of a line do in python?

Tags: python

I'm looking at the following piece of code:

```
totalDistance += \
      GetDistance(xCoords[i], yCoords[i],
                         xCoords[i+1], yCoords[i+1])
```

and can't understand what `+= \` means?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\` at the end of a line just indicates it will be continued on the next line as otherwise that (`totalDist +=`) would raise an error...   (also important to note that there can be nothing after the slash ... not even whitespace)

`+=` just adds and assigns back

```
x = 1
x += 1 # x is now 2  (same as  x = x + 1)
```

Comment: +1. Also, the reason it's so unfamiliar that most people don't know it is that you don't have to use it very often. In most cases, you've got an expression that is (or can be put) inside parentheses, brackets, or braces, in which case it's automatically continued; all you have to do is indent the next line properly. The only time this is really useful is cases like this, where you want to break right after an assignment operator.

Comment: @abarnert And even then, I believe the style guide PEP recommends just using a parenthesis around the expression instead.

Comment: @millimoose: An assignment is a statement, not an expression, so you can't wrap it in parens. So if you really do need to break right after the assignment operator, there's no alternative. (Of course it's very rare that you really do need to break right after the operator—e.g., you could just parenthesize the entire rhs—but I already explained that.)

Comment: @abarnert I've missed that in your phrasing I guess.

Answer (score 8):

The `\` escapes the line return immediately following it (there should not be any character between the `\` and the implicit `\n`).

There are also a few other exceptions; new lines are ignored when enclosed in the matching pairs of the following:

- `[]`
- `()`
- `{}`

In other words, the following are equivalent:

```
a= [1,2,3]
a = [1,
     2,
     3]
```

Comment: Addendum: newlines _and indentation_ are ignored when surrounded by parentheses

Answer (score 4):

The combination `\` followed by newline means line continuation. You can think of the `\` as escaping the newline, so that it doesn't have it's usual meaning of "line ending".

In Python, you can often arrange the code so that `\` is unnecessary, eg.

```
totalDistance += GetDistance(
                     xCoords[i], yCoords[i],
                     xCoords[i+1], yCoords[i+1])
```

here, the newlines don't end the line because they are inside the `()`